# Sum only first occurrence on a node in XSLT

Tags: group-by, sum, xslt-2.0, siblings

I'm running into a bit of a challenge. I'm working on summing the values contained in a child node without using a recursive template. I have a source similar to this:

```
<root>
   <entry>
      <recordID>001</recordID>
      <amount>500</amount>
   </entry>
   <entry>
      <recordID>001</recordID>
      <amount>200</amount>
   </entry>
   <entry>
      <recordID>002</recordID>
      <amount>500</amount>
   </entry>
   <entry>
      <recordID>003</recordID>
      <amount>400</amount>
   </entry>
   <entry>
      <recordID>004</recordID>
      <amount>100</amount>
   </entry>
</root>
```

What I'm trying to do is ONLY sum the FIRST occurrence of a recordID and count those nodes. I.e. I do not want to include the 2nd node. So the desired output would be

Record Count: 4
Total Amount: 1500

I've attempted to this, but it only returns 0. I'm not sure if it's because you can only reference siblings inside of a for each or not. but here was my first attempt:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">

<xsl:template match='root'>

   <xsl:value-of select='"Record Count: "'/>
   <xsl:value-of select='count(entry[recordID != following-sibling::recordID])'/>

   <xsl:value-of select='"Total Amount: "'/>
   <xsl:value-of select='sum(entry[recordID != following-sibling::recordID]/amount)'/>

</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

But this just returned 0.  I also tried this, but it was also unsuccessful

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">

<xsl:template match='root'>

   <xsl:value-of select='"Record Count: "'/>
   <xsl:for-each-group select='entry' group-by='.[recordID != following-sibling::recordID]'>
       <xsl:value-of select='count(current-group())'/>
   </xsl:for-each-group>

   <xsl:value-of select='"Total Amount: "'/>
   <xsl:for-each-group select='entry' group-by='.[recordID != following-sibling::recordID]'>
       <xsl:value-of select='sum(current-group()/amount)'/>
   </xsl:for-each-group>

</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

If anyone could offer some insight into how I could accomplish this, or corrections in my current code - I would greatly appreciate it!

Thanks in advance for any feedback

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an XSLT 2.0 example using [Muechian grouping](http://www.jenitennison.com/xslt/grouping/muenchian.xml) (with a slight adaption of simply using `is` instead of `generate-id` as XSLT 2.0 is assumed):

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">

<xsl:key name="entry-by-id" match="entry" use="recordID"/>

<xsl:variable name="first-records" select="root/entry[. is key('entry-by-id', recordID)[1]]"/>

<xsl:template match='root'>

   <xsl:value-of select='"Record Count: "'/>
   <xsl:value-of select='count($first-records)'/>

   <xsl:value-of select='"Total Amount: "'/>
   <xsl:value-of select='sum($first-records/amount)'/>

</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

With `for-each-group` you can use an approach like

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">

<xsl:template match='root'>

   <xsl:variable name="first-entries" as="element(entry)*">
        <xsl:for-each-group select='entry' group-by='recordID'>
            <xsl:copy-of select='.'/>
        </xsl:for-each-group>
    </xsl:variable>

   <xsl:value-of select='"Record Count: "'/>
   <xsl:value-of select='count($first-entries)'/>


   <xsl:value-of select='"Total Amount: "'/>
   <xsl:value-of select='sum($first-entries/amount)'/>


</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 0):

I've updated your first XSLT:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">

    <xsl:template match='root'>

        <xsl:value-of select='"Record Count: "'/>
        <xsl:value-of select='count(entry[not(recordID = preceding::entry/recordID)])'/>

        <xsl:value-of select='"Total Amount: "'/>
        <xsl:value-of select='sum(entry[not(recordID = preceding::entry/recordID)]/amount)'/>

    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Your XPATH, `entry[recordID != following-sibling::recordID]` won't give you the distinct `entry` elements(distinct by their `recordID`s), but my XPATH will.

Reason, 
`recordID != following-sibling::recordID`
means that you are checking if any of the *following-sibling recordIDs* have a different value than the current `recordID`(at the first place, there are no `recordID` siblings to any of the  `recordID`s in your input).

On the other hand when the xpath is:
`entry[not(recordID = preceding::entry/recordID)]`
The current `recordID` is matched with any of the preceding recordIDs, and the ones that match are ignored. This way only `entry` elements are grouped by `recordID`.

I suggest you to read about how `!=` operator works against `not()`:
`a != (b,c,d)` and `not(a = (b,c,d))` are not same.